# How does Android treat files bigger than free space remaining while recording?

Tags: file-system, insufficient-memory, system, ram

I've spent the entire day trying to solve this issue, it seems paranormal but (sadly) it's true and I didn't find a way to solve it.
Yesterday I recorded a very important video using my Xiaomi and Quick Video Recorder (I used it more than once and everything has always been great), **I had something like 3Gb of free space** but I didn't check it and I was recording with high quality. 
Android told me that was running out of space, so I suddenly stopped recording. 
I checked the video and used VLC to replay it and everything seemed to work fine.

**After about 30 minutes, the file was missing**. I checked everywhere, rooted the phone and tried with recovery applications such as Dr.Fone, but the file is completely disappeared.
To be 100% sure I didn't dream it I also checked on Google Takeout and it confirmed I actually used the camera during that time and suddenly opened VLC to replay it...

How's that possible? Does Android delete an entire video when it's too large? Is there a way to recover even a small portion or to show logs of camera activity to understand where's the file?

I didn't know what to do so I opened adb shell and tried with `ls -Rlat | grep '2019-12-18\ 17:'` (I was recording around 5pm) and that's the result:

```
drwxrwx--x   3 u0_a187 sdcard_rw 4096 2019-12-18 17:07 files
drwxrwx--x 3 u0_a187 sdcard_rw 4096 2019-12-18 17:07 .
drwxrwx--x 3 u0_a187 sdcard_rw   4096 2019-12-18 17:07 ..
drwxrwx--x 3 u0_a187 sdcard_rw   4096 2019-12-18 17:07 playlists
drwxrwx--x 3 u0_a187 sdcard_rw 4096 2019-12-18 17:07 .
drwxrwx--x 2 u0_a187 sdcard_rw 4096 2019-12-18 17:07 1576685265
drwxrwx--x 2 u0_a187 sdcard_rw 4096 2019-12-18 17:07 .
drwxrwx--x 3 u0_a187 sdcard_rw 4096 2019-12-18 17:07 ..
-rw-------  1 system system     0 2019-12-18 17:50 event_data@1576687815456.lost
-rw-------  1 system system     0 2019-12-18 17:08 event_data@1576685305699.lost
-rw-------  1 system system     0 2019-12-18 17:08 platform_stats_bookmark@1576685305937.lost
-rw-------  1 system system     0 2019-12-18 17:02 system_server_wtf@1576684937890.lost
drwx------  3 system system 4096 2019-12-18 17:34 org.videolan.vlc
drwx------  3 system system 4096 2019-12-18 17:24 com.kimcy929.secretvideorecorder
drwx------  3 system system 4096 2019-12-18 17:08 com.android.incallui
drwx------  3 system system 4096 2019-12-18 17:02 com.android.contacts
-rw------- 1 system system  897 2019-12-18 17:02 total
drwx------  3 system system 4096 2019-12-18 17:34 .
drwx------  2 system system 4096 2019-12-18 17:34 13020307
drwx------ 2 system system 4096 2019-12-18 17:34 .
drwx------ 3 system system 4096 2019-12-18 17:34 ..
drwx------  3 system system 4096 2019-12-18 17:24 .
drwx------  2 system system 4096 2019-12-18 17:24 245
drwx------ 2 system system 4096 2019-12-18 17:24 .
drwx------ 3 system system 4096 2019-12-18 17:24 ..
drwx------  3 system system 4096 2019-12-18 17:08 .
drwx------  2 system system 4096 2019-12-18 17:08 27
drwx------ 2 system system 4096 2019-12-18 17:08 .
drwx------ 3 system system 4096 2019-12-18 17:08 ..
drwx------  3 system system 4096 2019-12-18 17:02 .
drwx------  2 system system 4096 2019-12-18 17:02 100
drwx------ 2 system system 4096 2019-12-18 17:02 .
drwx------ 3 system system 4096 2019-12-18 17:02 ..
-rw-------  1 u0_a131 u0_a131     0 2019-12-18 17:33 com.facebook.katana_3c8406f3-3e8a-80cd-85cb-0c1211088d8d.v3.txt_anr
-rw-------  1 u0_a131 u0_a131     0 2019-12-18 17:33 com.facebook.katana_3c8406f3-3e8a-80cd-85cb-0c1211088d8d.v3.txt_native
-rw-------  1 u0_a131 u0_a131     0 2019-12-18 17:33 com.facebook.katana_3c8406f3-3e8a-80cd-85cb-0c1211088d8d.v3.txt_wrotedump
-rw-------  1 u0_a131 u0_a131   250 2019-12-18 17:33 com.facebook.katana_3c8406f3-3e8a-80cd-85cb-0c1211088d8d.v3.txt_static
drwx------   3 u0_a87 u0_a87        4096 2019-12-18 17:04 app_webview
drwxrws--x   4 u0_a87 u0_a87_cache  4096 2019-12-18 17:03 cache
drwxrwx--x   2 u0_a87 u0_a87        4096 2019-12-18 17:03 shared_prefs
drwx------  3 u0_a87 u0_a87 4096 2019-12-18 17:04 .
-rw-------  1 u0_a87 u0_a87  270 2019-12-18 17:04 pref_store
-rw-------  1 u0_a87 u0_a87 4885 2019-12-18 17:03 variations_seed_new
drwx------  3 u0_a87 u0_a87 4096 2019-12-18 17:03 Default
-rw-------  1 u0_a87 u0_a87    0 2019-12-18 17:03 variations_stamp
drwx------ 3 u0_a87 u0_a87  4096 2019-12-18 17:04 ..
drwx------ 3 u0_a87 u0_a87  4096 2019-12-18 17:03 .
-rw------- 1 u0_a87 u0_a87 61440 2019-12-18 17:03 Web Data
-rw------- 1 u0_a87 u0_a87     0 2019-12-18 17:03 Web Data-journal
drwx------ 3 u0_a87 u0_a87  4096 2019-12-18 17:03 blob_storage
drwx------ 3 u0_a87 u0_a87 4096 2019-12-18 17:03 .
drwx------ 3 u0_a87 u0_a87 4096 2019-12-18 17:03 ..
drwx------ 2 u0_a87 u0_a87 4096 2019-12-18 17:03 aa41e68b-5b8c-4030-ab9b-9fd7dfb95ee8
drwx------ 2 u0_a87 u0_a87 4096 2019-12-18 17:03 .
drwx------ 3 u0_a87 u0_a87 4096 2019-12-18 17:03 ..
drwxrws--x  6 u0_a87 u0_a87_cache  4096 2019-12-18 17:03 WebView
drwxrws--x  4 u0_a87 u0_a87_cache  4096 2019-12-18 17:03 .
drwxrws--x 6 u0_a87 u0_a87_cache  4096 2019-12-18 17:03 .
-rw------- 1 u0_a87 u0_a87_cache 19900 2019-12-18 17:03 font_unique_name_table.pb
drwxrws--x 4 u0_a87 u0_a87_cache  4096 2019-12-18 17:03 ..
drwx--S--- 3 u0_a87 u0_a87_cache  4096 2019-12-18 17:03 Default
drwxrws--x 6 u0_a87 u0_a87_cache 4096 2019-12-18 17:03 ..
drwx--S--- 3 u0_a87 u0_a87_cache 4096 2019-12-18 17:03 .
drwx--S--- 3 u0_a87 u0_a87_cache 4096 2019-12-18 17:03 ..
drwxrws--x 6 u0_a87 u0_a87_cache 4096 2019-12-18 17:03 ..
drwxrws--x 6 u0_a87 u0_a87_cache 4096 2019-12-18 17:03 ..
drwxrws--x 6 u0_a87 u0_a87_cache 4096 2019-12-18 17:03 ..
-rw------- 1 u0_a87 u0_a87_cache   40 2019-12-18 17:03 settings.dat
drwxrws--x 4 u0_a87 u0_a87_cache    4096 2019-12-18 17:03 ..
drwxrwx--x  2 u0_a87 u0_a87 4096 2019-12-18 17:03 .
-rw-rw----  1 u0_a87 u0_a87  127 2019-12-18 17:03 WebViewChromiumPrefs.xml
drwx--S---  2 u0_a16 u0_a16_cache   4096 2019-12-18 17:50 android_pay_temp_files
drwx--S---  2 u0_a16 u0_a16_cache   4096 2019-12-18 17:50 token_selector_anim
drwx--S---  6 u0_a16 u0_a16_cache   4096 2019-12-18 17:34 WebView
drwx--x--x  3 u0_a16 u0_a16_cache   4096 2019-12-18 17:14 oat
-rw-------  1 u0_a16 u0_a16_cache       0 2019-12-18 17:34 5Pvideo5Nmedia19I637855801993076728-1570660531011
-rw-------  1 u0_a16 u0_a16_cache       0 2019-12-18 17:34 5Pvideo5Nmedia20I4589217858447806657-1570753081747
-rw-------  1 u0_a16 u0_a16_cache       0 2019-12-18 17:34 5Pvideo5Nmedia20I5819926639731977934-1570751273785
drwx--S---  2 u0_a16 u0_a16_cache 4096 2019-12-18 17:50 .
drwx--S---  2 u0_a16 u0_a16_cache  4096 2019-12-18 17:50 .
-rw-------  1 u0_a16 u0_a16_cache 24641 2019-12-18 17:50 07e11acfb6ad0a8825abe06d691f5a7c
drwx--S---  6 u0_a16 u0_a16_cache  4096 2019-12-18 17:34 .
drwx--S---  2 u0_a16 u0_a16_cache  4096 2019-12-18 17:34 Crash Reports
drwx--S---  6 u0_a16 u0_a16_cache  4096 2019-12-18 17:34 Crashpad
drwx--S---  2 u0_a16 u0_a16_cache  4096 2019-12-18 17:34 SafeBrowsing
drwx--S--- 2 u0_a16 u0_a16_cache 4096 2019-12-18 17:34 .
drwx--S--- 6 u0_a16 u0_a16_cache 4096 2019-12-18 17:34 ..
drwx--S--- 6 u0_a16 u0_a16_cache 4096 2019-12-18 17:34 ..
drwx--S--- 6 u0_a16 u0_a16_cache 4096 2019-12-18 17:34 .
drwx--S--- 2 u0_a16 u0_a16_cache 4096 2019-12-18 17:34 attachments
drwx--S--- 2 u0_a16 u0_a16_cache 4096 2019-12-18 17:34 completed
drwx--S--- 2 u0_a16 u0_a16_cache 4096 2019-12-18 17:34 new
drwx--S--- 2 u0_a16 u0_a16_cache 4096 2019-12-18 17:34 pending
drwx--S--- 2 u0_a16 u0_a16_cache 4096 2019-12-18 17:34 .
drwx--S--- 6 u0_a16 u0_a16_cache 4096 2019-12-18 17:34 ..
drwx--S--- 2 u0_a16 u0_a16_cache 4096 2019-12-18 17:34 .
drwx--S--- 6 u0_a16 u0_a16_cache 4096 2019-12-18 17:34 ..
drwx--S--- 2 u0_a16 u0_a16_cache 4096 2019-12-18 17:34 .
drwx--S--- 6 u0_a16 u0_a16_cache 4096 2019-12-18 17:34 ..
drwx--S--- 2 u0_a16 u0_a16_cache 4096 2019-12-18 17:34 .
drwx--S--- 6 u0_a16 u0_a16_cache 4096 2019-12-18 17:34 ..
drwx--S--- 6 u0_a16 u0_a16_cache 4096 2019-12-18 17:34 ..
drwx--S--- 2 u0_a16 u0_a16_cache 4096 2019-12-18 17:34 .
drwx--S--- 4 u0_a16 u0_a16_cache 4096 2019-12-18 17:34 HTTP Cache
drwx--S--- 6 u0_a16 u0_a16_cache 4096 2019-12-18 17:34 ..
drwx--S--- 4 u0_a16 u0_a16_cache   4096 2019-12-18 17:34 .
-rw------- 1 u0_a16 u0_a16_cache 109082 2019-12-18 17:34 d495fa4a78df46ba_0
-rw------- 1 u0_a16 u0_a16_cache   5555 2019-12-18 17:34 dfe6b2497a7513ba_0
-rw------- 1 u0_a16 u0_a16_cache     24 2019-12-18 17:34 index
drwx--S--- 4 u0_a16 u0_a16_cache 4096 2019-12-18 17:34 ..
drwx--S--- 4 u0_a16 u0_a16_cache 4096 2019-12-18 17:34 ..
-rw------- 1 u0_a16 u0_a16_cache  280 2019-12-18 17:34 6aaed60636ee0201_0
-rw------- 1 u0_a16 u0_a16_cache   24 2019-12-18 17:34 index
drwx--x--x  3 u0_a16 u0_a16_cache 4096 2019-12-18 17:14 .
drwx--x--x  2 u0_a16 u0_a16       4096 2019-12-18 17:14 arm64
drwx--x--x 2 u0_a16 u0_a16        4096 2019-12-18 17:14 .
drwx--x--x 3 u0_a16 u0_a16_cache  4096 2019-12-18 17:14 ..
drwx------ 2 u0_a16 u0_a16 4096 2019-12-18 17:34 leveldb
drwx------ 2 u0_a16 u0_a16 4096 2019-12-18 17:34 .
-rw------- 1 u0_a16 u0_a16  322 2019-12-18 17:34 LOG
drwx--S---  2 u0_a305 u0_a305_cache 122880 2019-12-18 17:14 picasso-cache
drwx--S--- 2 u0_a305 u0_a305_cache  122880 2019-12-18 17:14 .
-rw-rw----  1 u0_a190 u0_a190 2511 2019-12-18 17:02 com.google.android.gms.appid.xml
-rw-rw----  1 u0_a190 u0_a190  168 2019-12-18 17:02 io.fabric.sdk.android:fabric:io.fabric.sdk.android.l.xml
-rw------- 1 u0_a190 u0_a190_cache  917285 2019-12-18 17:07 ded7ae5db1953d37df58cda73b06c144b288976c03223f6912a34c6b5180e8a2.0
drwxrws--x  10 u0_a143 u0_a143_cache  4096 2019-12-18 17:14 cache
drwxrws--x 10 u0_a143 u0_a143_cache  4096 2019-12-18 17:14 .
drwx--S---  4 u0_a143 u0_a143_cache 53248 2019-12-18 17:14 org.chromium.android_webview
drwx--S---  2 u0_a143 u0_a143_cache 24576 2019-12-18 17:14 picasso-cache
drwx--S---  3 u0_a143 u0_a143_cache  4096 2019-12-18 17:14 WebView
drwx--S---  4 u0_a143 u0_a143_cache  53248 2019-12-18 17:14 .
drwxrws--x 10 u0_a143 u0_a143_cache   4096 2019-12-18 17:14 ..
drwx--S--- 4 u0_a143 u0_a143_cache 53248 2019-12-18 17:14 ..
drwx--S--- 3 u0_a143 u0_a143_cache  8192 2019-12-18 17:14 js
drwx--S--- 4 u0_a143 u0_a143_cache 53248 2019-12-18 17:14 ..
drwx--S--- 3 u0_a143 u0_a143_cache   8192 2019-12-18 17:14 .
drwx--S--- 3 u0_a143 u0_a143_cache 8192 2019-12-18 17:14 ..
drwx--S---  2 u0_a143 u0_a143_cache 24576 2019-12-18 17:14 .
drwxrws--x 10 u0_a143 u0_a143_cache  4096 2019-12-18 17:14 ..
drwxrws--x 10 u0_a143 u0_a143_cache 4096 2019-12-18 17:14 ..
drwx--S---  3 u0_a143 u0_a143_cache 4096 2019-12-18 17:14 .
drwx--S---  2 u0_a143 u0_a143_cache 4096 2019-12-18 17:14 Crashpad
drwx--S--- 2 u0_a143 u0_a143_cache 4096 2019-12-18 17:14 .
drwx--S--- 3 u0_a143 u0_a143_cache 4096 2019-12-18 17:14 ..
drwxrws--x 10 u0_a143 u0_a143_cache  4096 2019-12-18 17:14 ..
drwxrws--x 10 u0_a143 u0_a143_cache 4096 2019-12-18 17:14 ..
drwxrws--x 10 u0_a143 u0_a143_cache 4096 2019-12-18 17:14 ..
drwxrws--x 10 u0_a143 u0_a143_cache  4096 2019-12-18 17:14 ..
drwxrws--x 10 u0_a143 u0_a143_cache 4096 2019-12-18 17:14 ..
drwxrws--x   7 u0_a118 u0_a118_cache  4096 2019-12-18 17:14 cache
drwx--S---  2 u0_a118 u0_a118_cache 12288 2019-12-18 17:14 fragment
drwx--S---  2 u0_a118 u0_a118_cache  8192 2019-12-18 17:14 header
drwx--S---  2 u0_a118 u0_a118_cache 28672 2019-12-18 17:14 volley
drwx--S---  2 u0_a118 u0_a118_cache 20480 2019-12-18 17:14 downloads
drwxrws--x  7 u0_a118 u0_a118_cache  4096 2019-12-18 17:14 .
drwx--S---  3 u0_a118 u0_a118_cache  4096 2019-12-18 17:14 cronet
drwx--S--- 2 u0_a118 u0_a118_cache   12288 2019-12-18 17:14 .
drwxrws--x 7 u0_a118 u0_a118_cache    4096 2019-12-18 17:14 ..
drwx--S--- 2 u0_a118 u0_a118_cache  8192 2019-12-18 17:14 .
drwxrws--x 7 u0_a118 u0_a118_cache  4096 2019-12-18 17:14 ..
drwx--S--- 2 u0_a118 u0_a118_cache   28672 2019-12-18 17:14 .
drwxrws--x 7 u0_a118 u0_a118_cache    4096 2019-12-18 17:14 ..
drwx--S--- 2 u0_a118 u0_a118_cache  20480 2019-12-18 17:14 .
drwxrws--x 7 u0_a118 u0_a118_cache   4096 2019-12-18 17:14 ..
drwx--S--- 3 u0_a118 u0_a118_cache 4096 2019-12-18 17:14 .
drwxrws--x 7 u0_a118 u0_a118_cache 4096 2019-12-18 17:14 ..
drwx--S--- 3 u0_a118 u0_a118_cache 4096 2019-12-18 17:14 ..
-rw-rw----  1 u0_a139 u0_a139   2513 2019-12-18 17:34 com.google.android.gms.appid.xml
-rw-rw----  1 u0_a139 u0_a139    411 2019-12-18 17:33 FBAdPrefs.xml
-rw-rw----  1 u0_a139 u0_a139    168 2019-12-18 17:33 io.fabric.sdk.android:fabric:io.fabric.sdk.android.l.xml
-rw------- 1 u0_a139 u0_a139_cache   49670 2019-12-18 17:34 20f9fcfcbe9fdb98_0
-rw------- 1 u0_a139 u0_a139_cache  109037 2019-12-18 17:34 f038e94cb33282ab_0
-rw-------  1 u0_a139 u0_a139 4885 2019-12-18 17:34 variations_seed
-rw-------  1 u0_a139 u0_a139    0 2019-12-18 17:34 variations_stamp
-rw------- 1 u0_a139 u0_a139 1467 2019-12-18 17:33 com.crashlytics.settings.json
drwxrwxr-x   3 media_rw u0_a20187 4096 2019-12-18 17:07 files
drwxrwxr-x 3 media_rw u0_a20187 4096 2019-12-18 17:07 .
drwxrwxr-x 3 media_rw u0_a20187   4096 2019-12-18 17:07 ..
drwxrwxr-x 3 media_rw u0_a20187   4096 2019-12-18 17:07 playlists
drwxrwxr-x 3 media_rw u0_a20187 4096 2019-12-18 17:07 .
drwxrwxr-x 2 media_rw u0_a20187 4096 2019-12-18 17:07 1576685265
drwxrwxr-x 2 media_rw u0_a20187 4096 2019-12-18 17:07 .
drwxrwxr-x 3 media_rw u0_a20187 4096 2019-12-18 17:07 ..
drwxrws--x   2 u0_a16 u0_a16_cache  4096 2019-12-18 17:22 cache
drwxrws--x  2 u0_a16 u0_a16_cache 4096 2019-12-18 17:22 .
-rw-------  1 u0_a16 u0_a16_cache    0 2019-12-18 17:22 .lib.lock
drwxrwx--x   3 u0_a187 sdcard_rw 4096 2019-12-18 17:07 files
drwxrwx--x 3 u0_a187 sdcard_rw 4096 2019-12-18 17:07 .
drwxrwx--x 3 u0_a187 sdcard_rw   4096 2019-12-18 17:07 ..
drwxrwx--x 3 u0_a187 sdcard_rw   4096 2019-12-18 17:07 playlists
drwxrwx--x 3 u0_a187 sdcard_rw 4096 2019-12-18 17:07 .
drwxrwx--x 2 u0_a187 sdcard_rw 4096 2019-12-18 17:07 1576685265
drwxrwx--x 2 u0_a187 sdcard_rw 4096 2019-12-18 17:07 .
drwxrwx--x 3 u0_a187 sdcard_rw 4096 2019-12-18 17:07 ..
drwxr-x---   3 u0_a187 everybody 4096 2019-12-18 17:07 files
drwxr-x--- 3 u0_a187 everybody 4096 2019-12-18 17:07 .
drwxr-x--- 3 u0_a187 everybody   4096 2019-12-18 17:07 ..
drwxr-x--- 3 u0_a187 everybody   4096 2019-12-18 17:07 playlists
drwxr-x--- 3 u0_a187 everybody 4096 2019-12-18 17:07 .
drwxr-x--- 2 u0_a187 everybody 4096 2019-12-18 17:07 1576685265
drwxr-x--- 2 u0_a187 everybody 4096 2019-12-18 17:07 .
drwxr-x--- 3 u0_a187 everybody 4096 2019-12-18 17:07 ..
drwxrwx---   3 u0_a187 everybody 4096 2019-12-18 17:07 files
drwxrwx--- 3 u0_a187 everybody 4096 2019-12-18 17:07 .
drwxrwx--- 3 u0_a187 everybody   4096 2019-12-18 17:07 ..
drwxrwx--- 3 u0_a187 everybody   4096 2019-12-18 17:07 playlists
drwxrwx--- 3 u0_a187 everybody 4096 2019-12-18 17:07 .
drwxrwx--- 2 u0_a187 everybody 4096 2019-12-18 17:07 1576685265
drwxrwx--- 2 u0_a187 everybody 4096 2019-12-18 17:07 .
drwxrwx--- 3 u0_a187 everybody 4096 2019-12-18 17:07 ..
```